# Questions about go-curl's OPT_COOKIEJAR option

Tags: go, libcurl

When using the OPT_COOKIEJAR option in go-curl, is there a way to check whether the work is completed?

If you run the source code below, there is a problem that ReadFile is executed before the cookie download is completed. I want to solve this.

```
  CommonSetopt(easy)
  easy.Setopt(curl.OPT_VERBOSE, 0)
  easy.Setopt(curl.OPT_COOKIEJAR, cookieName)
  easy.Setopt(curl.OPT_URL, string("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+gdriveID))

  log.Println("start download cookie: ", url)
  if err := easy.Perform(); err != nil {
      log.Println("cookie download fail: ", err)
      return
  }

  readBuf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(cookieName)
  if err != nil {
      log.Println("cookie read fail: ", err)
      return
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cleanup the session immediately after `easy.Perform` instead of cleaning up using a `defer` statement

```golang
  CommonSetopt(easy)
  easy.Setopt(curl.OPT_VERBOSE, 0)
  easy.Setopt(curl.OPT_COOKIEJAR, cookieName)
  easy.Setopt(curl.OPT_URL, string("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+gdriveID))

  log.Println("start download cookie: ", url)
  if err := easy.Perform(); err != nil {
      log.Println("cookie download fail: ", err)
      easy.Cleanup()
      return
  }
  // do cleanup
  easy.Cleanup()
  readBuf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(cookieName)
  if err != nil {
      log.Println("cookie read fail: ", err)
      return
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't know why the thank you comments keep getting deleted. Anyway the problem is solved.